# Algorithm to determine index of x/y grid

Tags: c, algorithm, raster

Okay i know there is another name for this operation but if i knew it, i would just search in google and find the correct algorithm. I hope you understand my intentions from the following diagram:

Ok, Lets assume we have a grid of for example 3x3 objects (.)

```
...
...
...
```

Each of these objects has index, starting from 0 and ending with 8

```
012
345
678
```

Then lets use the following loop:

```
w = 0; h = 0;
go :
w = 0;
for(; w<grid.width; w++)
{
    statuses[w][h] = isActor(CORESPONDENT_INDEX_GOES_HERE);
    if(w == grid.width-1 && h != grid.height-1)
    {
        h += 1;
        goto go;
    }
}
```

`isActor` is a function that returns the current object's status and it requires the correct index.

What should I put instead of `CORESPONDENT_INDEX_GOES_HERE`? If i use `w*h` it doesn't work and i know why. It won't return the correct index.

What shall be the correct algorithm for this?

Comment: @TioPepe How come what is `goto go` ? It is the loop keyword `goto` that remaps the compiler to the label `go`

Comment: Surely `w * h` is going to result in multiplication by zero? So, you'll be passing zero for several of the grid positions?

Comment: @Gareth yes it results a lot with multiplication by zero, since the first object of the width is aways with index 0

Comment: `w+h*3`? you should replace the goto with a for loop

Comment: @mch No. Why would i do that. The loop is working great.

Comment: index = `h * grid.width + w`?

Comment: That `goto` is ugly. Having 2 `for` loops would be more efficient.

Comment: @hk6279 I think that would do the job. It looks like a simple math that i couldn't comprehend. What a disappointment.

Answer (score 3):

As noted by hk6279, use `h * grid.width + w`.

This is called "raster scan". Unfortunately, no searching for "raster" reveals that formula.

Answer (score 0):

This represents a multidimensional array. In your case it is a 3 dimensional array.

The array is defined as arr[3][3]. Given that the index is calculated as follows:

```
      Column0 Column1 Column2

Row0    0       1      2
Row1    3       4      5
Row2    6       7      8

The index to access each of the values is:

Row0
arr[0][0] = 0
arr[0][1] = 1
arr[0][2] = 2

Row1
arr[1][0] = 3
arr[1][1] = 4
arr[1][2] = 5

Row2
arr[2][0] = 6
arr[2][1] = 7
arr[2][2] = 8
```

Comment: Hehe, yeah i know how to access them through the array.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to rewrite your code into something like this:

```
int gridsize = grid.width * grid.height; // be sure it doesn't overflow here
int index;
for (index = 0; index < gridsize; index++)
{
    int w = index % grid.width;
    int h = index / grid.width;
    statuses[w][h] = isObject(PIXEL.name, CORESPONDENT_INDEX_GOES_HERE);
}
```

The variable of `index` could be defined inside the `for` loop in `C11`:

```
for (int index = 0; index < gridsize; index++)
```

Comment: `h * grid.width + w` seems the correct algorithm after all. Thats what i needed.

Comment: @Edenia I understand, and there're also other ways to do this loop. However I'm suggesting that this is a better approach than your `goto` way. A good coding style saves time.

Comment: There is a reason why i picked up the way with the `goto`
I wanted to do as less code as possible and in the same time, parse the objects on a specific direction.

Comment: @Edenia If by "as less code as possible" what you mean is the code length, then your example counts 12 and mine counts 8. Besides it's way more important to write clean codes than short ones.

Comment: For me now is important to make a working one at firsts.

Answer (score 0):

see [live example in commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Fatou_sets_for_Blaschke_fraction_f(z)_%3D_rho_*_z%5E2_*_(z-3)_over_(1-3z)_with_LCM_and_critical_orbit.png):

```c
/* gives position of 2D point (ix,iy) in 1D array  ; uses also global variable iWidth */
unsigned int Give_i (unsigned int ix, unsigned int iy)
{
  return ix + iy * iWidth;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at/use `cellFromRowCol` from the terra (C++ code) or raster (R code) package

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(ncol=3, nrow=3)
cellFromRowCol(r, 2, 2) - 1
#[1] 4
```

(note the -1 because R indexing starts at 1, whereas you want to start at zero).

There is also

```
 cellFromXY(r, cbind(1,1))
```

Which is for (x, y) *coordinates*, not for row/col numbers.

These functions are vectorized, so you may not need a loop.